# Детские вопросы к песне «Потолок ледяной»

Tags: значение-слов, глаголы, поэзия, тропы

*У леса на опушке

Жила Зима в избушке.

Она снежки солила

В березовой кадушке.

Она сучила пряжу,

Она ткала холсты,

**Ковала ледяные

Да над реками мосты.***
.  .  .
*Ходила на охоту,

**Гранила серебро,**

Сажала тонкий месяц

В хрустальное ведро...*

[С. Островой. Зима](http://a-pesni.org/drugije/zima.htm)

1. Можно ли ковать мосты изо льда? Гранят ли серебро?
   Вообще-то это **детские вопросы** (в великому сожалению, я не смогла на них доходчиво ответить).
2. И уже вдогонку:
   Для чего Зима посадила месяц в ведро? И на кого она охотилась?

Comment: Если придираться, то можно спросить, как она торила санный путь. Для этого нужны сани, лошади, а о них нет ни слова.

Answer (score 3):

1) **Ковать можно различные металлы:** железо, медь, алюминий, в том числе и серебро. Например: «Подскажите, кто знает, как правильно ковать серебро, есть идея сделать подарочный набор из кованых серебряных изделий».  Огранка делается для изделий из камня, стекла, металла.

2) Но это всё в реальной жизни, **а у сказочной зимы основными материалами является прозрачный лёд, похожий на хрусталь, и белые снежные кружева, напоминающие кованое серебро**, которыми она украшает всё вокруг.  А если «ледяные изделия» припорошить сверху снегом, то они получат серебряную огранку.

3) **Ледяные мосты на реке**  – уже привычный образ.

Вспомним некрасовского Мороза-воеводу:  «Задумаю — реки большие Надолго упрячу под гнет, **Построю** мосты ледяные, Каких не построит народ».

Из современной поэзии: "Зима **сковала** реку льдом..."

Из словаря: **КОВАТЬ** 1. (нсв. ковать). что. Изготовить ковкой; выковать. 5. Заморозив, сделать твёрдым **или покрыть льдом;** оковать. Таким образом, переносное значение слова уже вошло в словарь. [http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=сковать](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Но у Зимы, как мне кажется,  есть мосты не только ледяные, **но и другие, кованые из серебра.** Обычный мост с деревянной резной оградой зима может превратить в кованое серебряное кружево.

4) **На кого охотится Зима?** Вот воевода Мороз любил припугнуть в зимнем лесу всё живое: «На горе недоброму вору, На страх седоку и коню, Люблю я в вечернюю пору Затеять в лесу трескотню». Трещат деревья на морозе, будто стреляют, и распугивают зверушек и птиц.

5) **И самый сложный образ — это молодой месяц в хрустальном ведре.** Если он молодой, то его надо вырастить, посадив в ведерко. Но для этого   месяц должен  ночью отразиться в темной воде, как в зеркале.

Это может быть незамерзшая в середине река с хрустальными берегами вокруг. Или если вы пойдете на колодец за водой, то ваши ведра превратятся в хрустальные, а в воде будет плавать молодой  месяц.

Ну и **прорубь** в реке, как мне подсказали, тоже напоминает круглое ведро, в котором ночью отражается месяц.

Comment: Есть такое выражение - реки скованы льдом. Понятно, что слово "скованы" здесь происходит от "оков", то есть,  связаны, ограничены. Но ведь "оковы" кто-то "ковал".

Comment: Любое изделие, имеющее грани, огранено по сути, в том числе, и серебряное.  Следовательно,  серебро гранить можно. А хрустальным ведром может выступить круглая прорубь.

Comment: Желательно добавить ссылку на словарь (о слове КОВАТЬ)

Comment: Исполняю Ваше желание, но, правда, словарь самый обычный, который на Грамоте.ру.

Comment: Это ссылка на СКОВАТЬ, а зима КОВАЛА.

Comment: Да, я не обратила внимание, что сковать (сов. вид) относится только к первому значению слова. Кстати, сначала я хотела отметить этот момент (ковала вместо сковала), но потом стерла, тогда отмечу сейчас. Это небольшая поэтическая вольность, вполне понятная: чтобы получить результат (сковать), надо же  эти мосты некоторое время ковать.

Answer (score 1):

> Ковала ледяные
>   Да над реками мосты.

Мосты ледяные, а не серебряные, "гранила серебро" к мостам не относится. Остается напрячь фантазию и представить, что лед ковкий, как металл.

> Гранила серебро

-

> [ГРАНИТЬ](http://m.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), -ню, -нишь; гранённый; -нён, -нена, -нено; нсв. (св. огранить). что. Обрабатывая резкой и шлифовкой что-л. твёрдое, делать грани. Г. алмаз, горный хрусталь. <Граниться, -ится; страд. Гранение, -я; ср. Алмазное г. Рисунки для гранения стекла (по стеклу). Гранильный, -ая, -ое. Г-ая мастерская, фабрика.
>
> [Алмазная огранка](https://aquamarine.gold/blog/yuvelirnye-khudozhestvennye-tekhniki-ot-drevnikh-do-sovremennykh/)
>   Это современная техника обработки **драгоценных металлов**. Ее принцип заключается в том, что золото и серебро под особым углом обрабатывают специальные резцы на разной глубине. После нанесения алмазной грани на украшении получаются тончайшие узоры, которые сверкают при любом свете, будто настоящие бриллианты.

Как видим, серебро гранят.

> Сажала тонкий месяц
>   В хрустальное ведро

Представляется ведро с водой, набранной из проруби или из колодца, а в нем месяц отражается. Ведро у зимы хрустальное, то есть из прозрачного льда, — это просто полет авторской фантазии. Для чего сажала? Может, чтобы подрос там в безопасности, а может просто чтобы им любоваться, как рыбкой в аквариуме.

> Ходила на охоту

Охотятся ради пропитания. Живя в лесной избушке, как-то нужно питаться, одними солеными снежками не насытишься.

А в общем, я думаю, песня не предполагает, что мы будем строго подходить к словам, просто дайте волю фантазии.

Comment: Да фантазировали мы! (Девочке шесть с половиной.) 1. Почему зимой месяц на небе такой яркий? Потому что Зима его посадила в хрустальное ведро и помыла-почистила. (С этого-то всё и началось.) 2. Почему тонкий? Потому что большой и круглый в ведерко не влезает, а большая кадушка уже занята. 3. Зима занимается фотоохотой (как простоквашинский Шарик? Да.) и проверкой - кто как спрятался от морозов...